# How to test Angular 4 field validation with async validator

Tags: validation, asynchronous

How do I test form with async validator? Could you please provide sample of the code.
I am testing email field below that has async validator using test below

```
email: ['', Validators.compose([                        Validators.composeAsync([                                                           emailValidator.validateEmail.bind(this)])]
                });


it('email field invalid because of domain', fakeAsync(() => {        
            const hostElement = fixture.nativeElement;
            const emailInput: HTMLInputElement = hostElement.querySelector('#email');
            emailInput.value = 'user@yahoo.com';
            emailInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

            fixture.detectChanges();
            const email = component.email;

            console.log('valid : ' + email.valid); //false
            console.log('errors : ' + JSON.stringify(email.errors)); // null
    });
```

Async validator returns observable with correct value printed in the console indicating an error but email does not have errors even though it is invalid.

What am I missing?
thank you